# How to append a pandas dataframe to a csv and if necessary create new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have an output called `df` that came from a pandas dataframe created within a loop of many films like this, so each `df` is the data for one film:

```
df = pandas.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['genre1', 'genre2', 'genre3', 'genre4'])
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('genre1_', ''))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('genre2_', ''))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('genre3_', ''))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('genre4_', ''))
df = pd.concat([df[col].sum(axis=1).rename(col) if len(df[col].shape)==2 else
                df[col] for col in df.columns.unique()],axis=1)
print(df)
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, mode='a', header=f.tell()==0)
```

but the problem is that with each loop there are different genres to the loop before.

So for the first loop the output looks like this:

```
title     runTime    comedy    action    drama   biography  ......
film1      90mins      1         1         1         1
```

which then gets assigned to the csv

But on the next iteration of the loop the next film is as follows:

```
title     runTime    comedy    action    history     ......
film2      90mins      1         1         1
```

I now what it to create a new column called `history` and have a one in that row for `film2` but a `0` for `film1` and assign `0` to the `biography` and `drama` columns on `film2`.

Currently it simply creates the first film as the default and then thinks every other film has the same genres.

So the first iteration produces a df that looks like this like this:

[image]

Second iteration looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm confused by what your renaming code is doing, could you enlighten me? It would also be good if we could see a before and after of the column names.

Comment: So, the code loops over a list of films in a csv. it then first each films produces a pandas dataframe with all the info; title, length, genres etc. Then for each film converts genre1, genre2, genre3 and genre4 into columns of comedy, action etc with 1 and 0s.

Comment: and then appends the csv "test" with each row (film)

Comment: but each iteration will have different headers due to the get_dummies part

Comment: Okay, tell me if I understood your comments correctly. You've got a bunch of DataFrames, each one containing information on a film. You're trying to combine all those DataFrames into one, with each film on a row, and a bunch of columns which indicate whether or not the film is part of a genre.

Comment: Yes, except that each film doesn't have every possible genre only the ones that the film had and a 1 associated with them. So then each dataframe doesn't have the same column headers because the column headers are the genres.

Comment: So when they are all joined together I would expect that for each film a lot of the genre columns will be empty or ideally contain 0s

Comment: Alright yes that makes sense! If you have some test data you could share, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have added two images that show the first and second iteration of the loop. So music and romance should have 0 assigned for the first film and horror and sci-fi should be zero on the second film

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200923/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-josh0798).

Comment: Can we get a copy of your for loop perhaps? That's where all of this breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to CSV file is what making it impossible, as you freezed the header, and don't have yet all you're potential headers.

an easier approach would be to create the full dataframe, and only then making the same as you already did, see next example code:

```
# initialize full dataframe    
df_full = pd.DataFrame()
#... loop reading df of one film data
# once created the raw df, you would do:
df_full = pd.concat([df_full,df])
# when finished run you're code on df_full like:
df_full = pandas.get_dummies(data=df_full, columns=['genre1', 'genre2', 'genre3', 'genre4'])
# continue with the rest of your code, eventually writing the csv file
```

Acording to OP comment, I've written the code to handle this situation,
when can't do it in memory:

```
# initialize the full set of genres list and genre fix columns
full_genre_cols = set()
genre_cols = ['genre1', 'genre2', 'genre3', 'genre4']
# taking created raw dataframe and keeping new genres
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=genre_cols, prefix_sep='', prefix='')
actual_genre_cols = df.drop(non_genre_cols, axis=1).columns
full_genre_cols.update(actual_genre_cols)
# ... finish reading all dataframes, and start over 
# this time create full columns dataframes, and append them to CSV file
# preparing raw df and transform
non_genre_cols = df.drop(genre_cols, axis=1).columns
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=genre_cols, prefix_sep='', prefix='')
actual_genre_cols = df.drop(non_genre_cols, axis=1).columns
# preparing full columns dataframe
full_cols = list(non_genre_cols)
full_cols.extend(full_genre_cols)
df_fullcols = pd.DataFrame(columns=full_cols)
# updating with current values the correct genre columns
# and resetting to 0 all NaN of genres that not exist in this current cycle
df_fullcols[actual_genre_cols] = df[actual_genre_cols]
df_fullcols.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# and now only left to append to file
with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    df_fullcols.to_csv(f, mode='a', header=f.tell()==0)
```

Comment: I attempted to do something like that but I got memory errors when creating the appending each list to a dataframe and then outputting the entird df to csv.

Comment: The appraoch should be the same, meaning, you first need to read all data but only create a set (every genre will show only once) with all read columns.
Only then reread your data this time write a header with all columns set, and each time you create one film df, it should have columns with all of your set, so it will append to CSV with the correct values at place (zeros for non existent headers at this read cycle).

Nevertheless unless you have a very big list (millions rows), or a very low memory system (less than 4GB) you should check you're code as it shouldn't get to memory errors.